# Multiplot for creating zoom charts

Tags: gnuplot

I want to use multiplot in a way that there is one big chart and one small chart. The small chart in the magnified version of the big chart. There is a good example [here](http://ontublog.blogspot.com.br/2009/10/plots-inside-other-plots-with-gnuplot.html) but my scales are different from the example and I found that setting the correct size and origin values very hard!

I want to draw something like this

[image]

The data file contains simple integer numbers like

```
10000
20300
12340
10
40000
...
```

The xrange is [0:4000000] and yrange is [0:4000000] I want to zoom X from 100000 to 300000

Hard thing for me is **how to put the small chart in the right of the big chart? top or bottom doesn't matter.**

UPDATE:

When I set the origin of the second chart to `set origin 0.8,0.8`, I see that the second chart is on top right, but the canvas doesn't scale correctly.

`set origin 0.6, 0.6`
[image]

`set origin 0.8, 0.8`
[image]

Comment: You can either use `set origin` and `set size`, like done in the example you linked, or you can use `set lmargin` etc. to set explicit margins for the inset. Not very handy, but thats the way to go.

Comment: I know that I have to play with them. Problem is, if I set a wrong value, I see that one of the chart is never plotted. I don't know, is it far beyond the plot area or not. I want to know, is there any relation between the the X-Y ranges and origin and size? I mean, when the X range is 0:4M, should I set the origin of the other plot to `set origin 6000000,0`??

Comment: Ok, I get your problem. The values given to `set origin` are in screen coordinates, i.e. `set origin 0,0` sets the origin to the lower left, and `set origin 0.5,0.5` to the center of the canvas. So just try using `set origin 0.6,0.6; set size 0.4,0.4` as first try.

Comment: Right, the scaling isn't done automatically which is why you need to use `set size` as I said. Use `set size 0.2,0.2` for the inset together with your `set origin 0.8,0.8`.

Comment: Are you sure about that? the mentioned set size will squeeze the second chart

Comment: Yes it shrinks the second chart. Buts that's what you want, or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57422/discussion-between-mahmood-and-christoph).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `set size` in combination with `set origin` to scale and shift your plots. Or you could use `set lmargin` etc. to control the size of the plots with respect to the image size (i.e. the canvas size). (Of course you could also combine those parameters)

Here is a sample script which uses only the `size` and the `origin`. The values given to `set size` are in screen coordinates. So `set size 1,1` is the default and the plot area plus all margins corresponds to the canvas size. With `set size 0.5,1` you scale the plot's to 50% of the canvas width. Also `set origin` uses this kind of coordinates.

Since you want to place both plots side-by-side, You can use an image size with a large aspect ratio (`set terminal pdfcairo size 4in,2in`).

```
set term pdfcairo size 4,2
set output 'foobar.pdf'

set multiplot

unset tics
set border 3

set origin 0,0
set size 0.8,1
plot x**2

set origin 0.75,0.2
set size 0.25,0.3
plot x

unset multiplot
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer in this  [post](http://ontublog.blogspot.com.br/2009/10/plots-inside-other-plots-with-gnuplot.html) or in this [another plot](http://www.gnuplotting.org/zooming-in-with-multiplot/). The trick is to play with *set size* and *set origin*